# create audit report farm level in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

how to create audit report farm level in SharePoint 2013 , how to remove the audit report based on time

Comment: In farm level ! what is the type of object/data that you need audit it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to configure audit settings for entire farm you have to configure the settings for each and every site collection under the web application, use the sample code to configure programmatically or follow the steps to configure through UI, you can follow instructions from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b36c2170-698d-41d5-92bc-93187a68082a/creating-sharepoint-auditing-reports-at-farm-level?forum=sharepointadminprevious).

You can enable auditing on these levels: site collection, library/list, folder, and content type.

**Site Collection** - Go to Site Actions –> Site Settings –> Site Collection Administration –> Site Collection audit settings.
Under the Document and Items section you can enable the events you would like to audit.

**Library/list** - Go to [yourlibrary] –> Library Tools/Library –> Library Settings –> Permissions and Management –> Information management policy settings.
Under the Content Types Policies section you can define a new policy or choose an existing policy (created in the site collection).

**Audit log trimming** - By enabling auditing in a SharePoint environment with a large number of events, you will potentially end up with a large audit log which can affect the over all performance. It is recommended to enable audit log trimming for site collections with extensive auditing.
Go to Site Actions –> Site Settings –> Site Collection Administration –> Site Collection audit settings.

Learn to configure diagnostic logging in SharePoint 2013 from the SharePoint Central Administration website or by using Windows PowerShell, to check if there is the information about the permission change in the web application level: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748656.aspx

Another option is to try [SharePoint auditing solution](https://www.lepide.com/lepideauditor/sharepoint-auditing.html) that provides details of activities on the SharePoint Farm everyday which tracks, audits, reports and alerts on changes to SharePoint farms, servers, sites, users, permissions and more.

Thanks,